# how to use pure javascript in a blazor component?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, blazor

*I get this error on the chrome console *

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at site.js?v=kl3xhIVhcNXQPtfwvl8lWxAS82rpgIYeNY7RJb9nyrI:9:7
`let btn = document.querySelector(".btn-primary");

everytime I try to add an event listener to a button from a blazor component.

why is this not working on a blazor component , or what I am doing wrong.

--js code--

let btn = document.querySelector(".btn-primary");

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
alert("HE");
});`

I am trying to use js from an external file , trying to grab any html element from a blazor component and it is not working.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: If you call you js method right after you set some binded property that makes your component visible, it is not in dom already and will appear after rerender. There is workaround, you can wrap your js code in setTimeout(function() {your code}, 0); but I'm not sure about it's stability, in my case it always works.

Comment: Where are you invoking your javascript? It sounds like you are not calling it in the `OnAfterRender[Async]` event. A quick read through the [component lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0) may help you to understand when the DOM is available in a Blazor app.